# How to expand particular entities navigation property

Tags: rest, odata, dynamics-business-central

By using "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/Production/api/v2.0/$metadata", I'm able to retrieve all entities structure. I need to parse through particular entity and expand its navigation properties

I'm trying to retrieve particular entity properties and expand its navigation properties.I'm not able to form api.